# Need to load an AEM form with a particular record prepopulated

Tags: aem

We have an AEM form pointed to a data model. The data model is pointing to a MySQL table.

We would need to show that form with a particular record pre-populated. For example, we have a student form and we need to load the form with data populated for student_id=5. By default the AEM forms gets pre-populated with the record for student_id=1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to include more details in your question, for example some code

Comment: You can set the value of the `student_id` in request attribute and configure your model to read the value from the request attribute. It would then use that value to pull the right record from DB and prepopulate your form.

Comment: Hi, 
I have configured the get service in the data model, so that it fetches the particular record corresponding to that student id. I have tested the model and it is working fine.

@rakhi4110, As you have suggested, provided the student id in request param as follows:

"http://localhost:4504/content/dam/formsanddocuments/student/jcr:content?wcmmode=disabled&student_id=3"

But still the form is loading with 1st record. I think I am missing some configuration. Could you please provide me that pointer?

Comment: Hi
I configured the data model to read value from request attribute.

Test result is::
Input -
{
    "request": {
        "attribute": {
            "id": "3"
        }
    }
}

Output -
{
    "student": {
        "address": "WIPRO KOLKATA",
        "gender": "female",
        "father_name": "vinod mehera",
        "dob": "03-10-1992",
        "student_id": 3      
    }
}

While loading the form with "formsanddocuments/student/jcr:content?wcmmode=disabled&student_id=3"

no data is getting populatef. I hv configured Form Data model prefill service in that form

Comment: @SuswanMondal - Request attribute is different to request parameter. The form doesn't use the request parameter. You need to read the parameter in your code and set it as a request attribute using `request.setAttribute(attrName, value);`. Configure this `attrName` in your model and the form should pick the right value

Comment: @rakhi4110,
Thanks for your reply. As told already, I configured the data model to read value from request attribute. 
And I have set request.setAttribute() in the AEM servlet.

String url2 = "../content/dam/formsanddocuments/existing-student-step1/jcr:content";
request.setAttribute("id", "2");
   
dispatcher.forward( request, response );

Now the form is loading when I hit the servlet from browser (https://localhost:8443/bin/loadStudentData). But data is not getting populated in the form.